# pdfkit: size in mm not correct

Tags: python, pdfkit

here is a minimal html file with a box configured with height 50mm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
        .rectangle {
            display: block;
            height: 50mm;
            border: 1px solid black;
            font-size: 20pat;
            text-align: center;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="rectangle">↑<br>50mm<br>↓</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I convert it into a pdf file by

```
import pdfkit

options = {
    'margin-top': '0.3cm',
    'margin-right': '0.5cm',
    'margin-bottom': '0.0cm',
    'margin-left': '0.0cm',
    'page-size': 'A4',
    'copies': 1,
    }

pdfkit.from_file( "my.html", "my.pdf", options=options)
```

After having printed it I dont see that the rectangle has really the height 50 mm, it is much smaller. I searched for ours in the web to find out why 50 mm in html are not 50 mm in pdf but found no answer. Could somebody help? Try and error to find out which size I should configure to have a box with really 50mm height is boring.

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Comment: You didn't tell us how you determined "it is not 50mm", and didn't tell us the magnitude of the error. Did you print the PDF and use a ruler? Measured it on-screen? Perhaps there is A4 vs U.S. lettersize confusion. I recommend you write a loop that produces several rectangles of similar sizes. One of them will be close to 50mm.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you, J_H. Unfortunately that doesn't help very much. As I wrote the 50mm rectangle is just the minimal example. The original HTML is a complex design of an invoice with image, some columns, header, footer, and so on. I determined the 50 mm issue by printing the PDF and measuring with a ruler. The printed 50 mm rectangle has a height of 40 mm.

Comment: Cool. Sounds like a simple scaling problem. If you desire X mm, just specify 1.25 × X, and it will come out as you wish. (I imagine there is CSS, an outer <div>, or something else in the system that is scaling in a way that you wish it wouldn't. But you can still scale back in the other direction to obtain the desired result in the end.)

Comment: Ok, multiplying with 1.25 works fine. Anyhow I am a bit unhappy since I did not find out the reason for this scaling. The code obove is really simple, there is no scalling at all. What I  did not write: I used pdfkit to convert the HTML to a PDF file. But I did not find any information about a possible scalling by pdfkit.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a simple scaling problem.

If you desire X mm, just specify 1.25 × X, and it will come out as you wish.

---

The OP validates this.

> Ok, multiplying with 1.25 works fine.